# iOS Swift :How to port the following Objective C method to Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am learning Swift and trying to learn all the ends and out about it.

This is the Objective C code I am trying to port to Swift.

```
NSInteger sort(id num1, id num2, void *context) {
int v1 = [num1 intValue];
int v2 = [num2 intValue];
if (v1 < v2)
 return NSOrderedAscending;
else if (v1 > v2)
return NSOrderedDescending;
else
return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

This is what I have so far.

```
func sort (num1 : AnyObject , num2 : AnyObject , context : Void) -> NSInteger

{
    var v1 : Int = num1.integerValue
    var v2 : Int = num2.integerValue


    if (v1 < v2) {
        return NSOrderedAscending
    }
    else if (v1 > v2) {
        return NSOrderedDescending
    }
    else {
        return NSOrderedSame
    }
}
```

The problem with this method is NSOrderedAscending doesn't seem to exist and I believe I have the method name is all wrong. Any tips or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Your code snippet appears to be taken from Apple's example in the documentation of `NSArray`'s `sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:` method, so I'll add that that method is from before ObjC had blocks and you probably shouldn't use it in ObjC and you definitely shouldn't use it in Swift.

Comment: Good find @dan. I was wondering where this code came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues that make a direct port non-trivial.

For one thing, the Objective-C code calls the `intValue` method on the object. This suggests that the objects being passed to the function are expected to be `NSString` instances, so the Swift function should really take `NSString` arguments, not `AnyObject` arguments (unless the function really *can* take any type of object, in which case see the note below). Also, the `context` argument isn't being used at all, so it's not really necessary. Also, the return type is actually `NSComparisonResult`, not `NSInteger`. Given that, the Swift version would look something like:

```
func sort(num1: NSString, num2: NSString) -> NSComparisonResult {
    let v1 = num1.intValue
    let v2 = num2.intValue
    if v1 < v2 {
        return NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
    } else if v1 == v2 {
        return NSComparisonResult.Same
    } else {
        return NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
    }
}
```

---

If the Swift version really *does* need to operate on any type of object, then it would be better to use a conditional cast:

```
func sort(num1: AnyObject, num2: AnyObject) -> NSComparisonResult {
    if let n1 = num1 as? NSString {
        if let n2 = num2 as? NSString {
            let v1 = n1.intValue
            let v2 = n2.intValue
            if v1 < v2 {
                return NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
            } else if v1 > v2 {
                return NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
            }
        }
    }
    return NSComparisonResult.Same
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This function is dangerous and somewhat surprising in ObjC. It is extremely surprising in Swift and unlikely to be very useful.

In ObjC, this is mostly just reimplementing `compare:`. The fact that it's passing `id` rather than some specific type (`NSString` maybe?) makes it very dangerous. There's no promise that `intValue` is implemented on what you pass. In Swift, passing the correct type is even more important. But in any case, whatever is calling this would probably do better by accepting a closure or function. It's not clear what the goal is here.

Your porting of `context` is not correct. `Void` does not equate to `void*`. It equates to `()`, which is quite different. The fact that you're not using context suggests that maybe you should avoid porting that, and just rework the calling code to be more Swift-like.

Mechanically converting ObjC code into Swift is very likely to create very bad Swift. In particular, if you find yourself using `AnyObject` very often, you are probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift, the return values are written as such:

```
NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
NSComparisonResult.Same
```